# WritableBitmap: Compiler complains that type can't be found but intellisense can find it

Tags: f#, image-manipulation

I am learning F# by converting a program in C# to F#

The problem is with WritableBitmap, the compiler complains that:
 `The type tableBitmap is not defined`
this is the code:

```
module MandelbrotBitmap
open System.Windows.Media
open System.Windows.Media.Imaging

type Mandelbrot(width:int) as this =
    let mutable _width = width
    let mutable _height = 10
    let mutable bitmap = new WritableBitmap( _width, _heights, 96.0, 96.0,
       PixelFormats.Bgr32, None)

    member this.Width 
        with get() = _width
        and set(newVal) = _width <- newVal
```

The `None` in the instanciation is my try to replace `null` in the original expression.
I have `PresentationCore` and `WindowsBase` in my references.

```
      bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
                (int)sizeInfo.NewSize.Width, 
                (int)sizeInfo.NewSize.Height, 
                96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
```

WriteableBitmap is described in this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx)

My question is; *What is the compiler complaining about?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two typos: WritableBitmap should be *WriteableBitmap*, and _heights should be _*height*. Also, `null` and `None` are not interchangeable, when you are using .NET framework classes often times you must use `null`, which is a interop feature of F#. One last problem, if you want to break apart your arguments across lines in the WriteableBitmap constructor, you need to make sure the next line is farther indented than `new` since whitespace is significant in F#. Here is the final, fixed WriteableBitmap constructor call:

```
new WriteableBitmap( _width, _height, 96.0, 96.0, 
    PixelFormats.Bgr32, null)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also helpful was the comment about null and None + 1. When I wrote the question I broke apart the arguments for the benefit of readibility. Works as a charm now.

Comment: Great, glad to help. You know, if you don't have the commercial version of VS2008 or 10, you can easily download and install VS2008 or 10 Shell and F# 2.0 CTP release for free and get great intellisense with F#: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/release.aspx

Comment: Mild correction, you *can* break apart the arguments, but the ones on the subsequent lines have to be indented further than the `new`.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a typo:

```
let mutable bitmap = new WriteableBitmap( _width, _heights, 96.0, 96.0,
    PixelFormats.Bgr32, None)
```

Answer (score 2):

there are few typos in your code: *WriteableBitmap* and _*heights*